# Erratic behaviour during translation

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are experiencing erratic translation behaviour, and have been now for a few days. Some examples:

- single .ipt files not translating (Inventor 2016 and 2014 tested)
- An .ipt file that won't translate as a single file translates fine when uploaded as part of an assembly, where it can clearly be viewed.
- Step and SolidWorks files that have worked previously no longer translating.

We can translate a small number of assemblies successfully, which indicates it is not a problem with our code. Below is a typical manifest that we are getting from these errors.It's a step file that was exported from Inventor 2016. It successfully translates and is viewable within A360 but not with the Forge APIs.

```
{
 "type": "manifest",
 "hasThumbnail": "false",
 "status": "failed",
 "progress": "complete",
 "region": "US",
 "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Y2Fkc2hhcmUtZGV2LWJ1Y2tldC9TaGFmdC5zdHA",
 "version": "1.0",
 "derivatives": [
   {
     "name": "Shaft.stp",
     "hasThumbnail": "false",
     "status": "failed",
     "progress": "complete",
     "messages": [
       {
         "type": "error",
         "code": "ATF-1025",
         "message": [
           "The file: {0} is corrupt or invalid.",
           "C:\\worker\\viewing-atf-lmv\\tmp\\job-1\\6\\Shaft.stp"
         ]
       },
       {
         "type": "error",
         "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870943",
         "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
       }
     ],
     "outputType": "svf"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, so, can I understand a simple Inventor 2016 ipt file cannot work?  but I tested it just now, it can still work. Could you elaborate how you created this ipt, and share other models (after removing your confidential info) .As replying in the other of your thread, I doubt it might probably because of the uploading process which makes Forge thought it is an invalid file. However, from what you described here, it sounds more specific scenarios. So some demo models will be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Fixed! Turns out there were 2 issues in play, confusing our diagnosis. As you suggested, we were uploading smaller models by form data directly, now changed to file stream. We also had a caching issue with our token, which were giving us a 401 error. Now also fixed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am also experiencing this out of the blue, but am having trouble tracing it. Can you share in an answer how you fixed this @ChrisAcheson? Could you also link to the 'other thread' Xiaodong mentions please?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem with this exact message.
In my case, the cause of the problem was that the stream of the file i was uploading wasn't on it's beggining, so i just did a `fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` and then it worked for me.